# How to access methods of a service from its calling activity?

Tags: android, object, android-activity, android-service, service-object

I have a doubt regarding using service. Is it necessary to create an object of a service in order to start it or simply declaring a service variable is sufficient?

I want to know that whether a service is started by creating its object or you need to explicitly start the service by calling the start service method?

```
GPSService trackerService = new GPSService(RunningActivity.this);
```

Does the above line start the activity? Or it gets started on calling

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(RunningActivity.this, GPSService.class);
startService(serviceIntent);
```

All I need is I want to access the service objects in my activity.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the question ?. Look at the android docummentation about service http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: I asked this question only because I could not find relevant reply. Please help me with a solution if you have. I want to access methods of the service in my activity. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instantiate a `Service`. Only the Android framework can do that. You start a service by calling `startService()`.

Comment: What if I want to access the method of my service e.g. service has a method called startTracking(). Can I use that by writing myservice.startTracking()? What steps I need to follow before doing that?

Comment: You cannot call methods from your `Service` unless they are `static`. If you need to call methods in your `Service` look at how to bind to a service and use AIDL (remote procedure calls).

Comment: Ok @DavidWasser I will see that. Thank you.